# Windows 7 installer asks for disk drivers even though C: is available (disk already detected)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, sata, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 on a Lenovo Legion Y520.

It uses the Intel 100 Series C230 SATA controller.

During the install, Windows 7 produces an error that it is missing the disk drivers. However, when I select "browse" to find device drivers, I see that the existing Windows partition is already mounted. So it seems the included SATA drivers are already working.

I tried this with the "AHCI" BIOS option as well as Intel Premium RST RAID enabled.

I downloaded the [Intel RST driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/23496/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-), and the Windows 7 Installer claims to have successfully installed the driver, but still claims that no new drives are available.

Why does Windows 7 Installer tell me that it cannot detect disks when it obviously is detecting the disk and mounting partitions on it?

Comment: At which point in the install does it pop up with the error?  What's the EXACT error it's showing you?

Comment: Immediately after choosing "Install Now", where you would normally select a disk or partitioning options.

Comment: As asked, what's the exact error message it's showing you? :)

Comment: if you install win7 from a USB thumb drive, use the 1 USB2 port, not the USB3 ports